# Can't find suitable MySQL collation to distinguish a and á

Tags: mysql, search, collation

I've got symbols like a and á in my database. They are the same when I set up collation utf8_general_ci and they are different when I choose unf8bin.
I'd like to keep them different but make search case-insensitive. Is it possible with some default collation?

Comment: There is a documentation page on making your own collation.  _Lots_ of other people would like what you are asking for.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for confirming my thoughts.

Comment: By the way do you know where I can download custom collation file that is ready for use?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no such collation in MySQL for utf8 (or utf8mb4).

`SHOW COLLATION LIKE '%cs';` will list the small number of _cs collations in other encodings (latin1, etc).

You can use some combination of these, but they are costly:

```
WHERE UPPER(x) = UPPER(y)
WHERE x = y COLLATE utf8_bin
```

In German, the `ß` may be problematical:

```
mysql> SELECT 'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
+-------------------------------------+
| 'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, that's an option but I can't do that. CMS doesn't allow it without core modifying.So the own collation is the only way.